# Centering a div inside div, html

Tags: html, css, center

I have 3 divs in a div and I want to center the bottom one. I've tried every hint I've found on the net (a you can see in my code...), but nothing works.
This should be fairly easy, but it just won't center.

```
.container  {
position: relative; 
width: 968px;   
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center;
}

.text       { 
position: absolute;  
width: 968px; 
height: 100px;">
}     

.bg_image       {
position: absolute;   
width: 968px; 
height: 545px; 
top: 150px; 
background-image: url(x.jpg);
} 

.bg_image2      { 
position: absolute; 
display: block; 
width: 50%; 
margin: 0 auto;   
height: 200px; 
top: 545px; 
background-image: url(x.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This question is here about 3 times a day. Try using the search function.

Comment: Again and again.

[Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a typo in .text (a double quote sign). Also, please provide a prototype giving us a base to work on (jsfiddle.net or codepen.io). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: show your problem in fiddle. So that it is easy to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your css code there's an error in .text remove this "> after height: 100px;
Secondly we can't answer this if you don't add your html code.

Comment: I know you can't comment yet, but this is not an answer. You may want to consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example code may help you..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html > 
    <head> 
     <style type="text/css"> 
    #outer{ position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; } 
    #inner1{ width: 50%; height: 20%; top: 25%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; background:orange; } 
    #inner2{ width: 50%; height: 40%; top: 25%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; background:red; } 
     </style> 
    </head> 
       <body> 
         <div id=outer> 
           <div id=inner1> </div> 
           <div id=inner2> </div> 
         </div> 
       </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a `fixed width` eg(width:100px;) and `margin:0 auto;` whichever Div you want to make in center.

This will work for you.

```
.centerDiv{
width:100px;   /*as per your choice but width should be fixed.*/
height:100px; /*as per your choice even you can add auto*/
margin:0 auto; /*this is important to make div in center.*/
}
```